# how to check that all of the images on a page have a src attribute that is not empty?

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js

How can I check that all of the images on a page have a src attribute that is not empty using nightwatch.js? I have a page of images and sometimes the src attribute is empty. I want to check for that

Answer (score 2):

By using an XPath Selenium locator like this:

```
.//img[@src[not(string())]]
```

Or , for non-empty:

```
.//img[@src[string()]]
```

I am guessing here, but to get the list of elements so you can assert on the size of the list, get them like this:

```
return this.client.useXpath().elements('/xpath/expression');
```

Comment: I want to use assert so that it fails if src attribute of any image is empty

Comment: No, it works.  I just verified on the main google.com homepage.  Those locators are good.   Use Firefox Firepath and you will see.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `getAttribute` command to fetch the `src` attribute of your image and then assert in the callback. For example:

```
client.getAttribute(".container img", "src", function (result) {
  this.assert.equal(typeof result, "object");
  this.assert.equal(result.status, 0);
  this.assert.ok(result.value);
});
```

More about `getAttribute`: http://nightwatchjs.org/api#getAttribute

Answer (score 1):

you can compare the length of the results returned by
     img

and
     img[src]

The first CSS selector will get all img tags, the 2nd will get all img tags with the src property defined.